# Is SqliteParameter.SqliteType relevant on insert?

Tags: microsoft.data.sqlite

Using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite, when inserting a new row using Parameters, do I need to consider SqliteParameter.DbType and/or SqliteParameter.SqliteType?

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteparameter?view=msdata-sqlite-7.0.0) states

> Due to SQLite's dynamic type system, parameter values are not converted.

So this means that the types are irrelevant, because Microsoft.Data.Sqlite will not apply any kind of conversion to the values. Is this correct?